# Expo Snack app based on @react-navigation/native works on its Web variant but it crashes as it is started both on its Android and on its iOS variants

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I've been trying to write React Native apps on Expo's Snack Web interface.

Here's the code I've been playing with [2].

It runs smoothly on its Web incarnation but as I choose its Android or iOS variants, the same error is given by Expo Go app startup time:

```
**0,a.usePreventRemoveContext is not a function (it is undefined)**

TypeError: 0,a.usePreventRemoveContext is not a function (it is undefined)

  at anonymous (@react-navigation/native.stack:12:14200)
  at S (@react-navigation/native.stack:3:14943)
```

Some hours of Internet search have severely contributed to my confusion, and by this point, I would guess there is something wrong with my dependencies' versions.

I have tried to combine dependencies versions, and I have also tried to import components from different navigation libraries.

Additionally, I've built different navigation structures. All of them went smoothly on Snack's Web variant, but as I switched to Android or iOS, the very same error was thrown.

Probably, as I import `NavigationContainer` from `@react-navigation/native` in order to play with the navigable stack of `View` components, something loads wrongly on app startup.

Well, the code and the `package.json` dependencies file can all be seen on [2], and the latter is also available next, for the sake of convenience.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Anyway, I'm not even sure if this is a version compatibility issue. But on [2] you can test it, it's public code.

So, what's wrong there? Please, help?

**REFERENCES**

[1] Snack
https://snack.expo.dev/

[2] Projeto_RH_em_Acao
https://snack.expo.dev/@marcio.barbado/projeto_rh_em_acao

Answer (score 0):

Change your dependencies to:

```
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

When i reviewed your code there is some missing elements
On your RegisterView page you used a style called btnText but there isn't any style named that.
I can recommend for you to use some linter and try again